# Slack bot to popup dialog and request user input when post is made to channel's root

Tags: slack-api

When a Slack user goes to post a comment in a channel's root (not as a reply to an existing post, a.k.a "thread"), I would like Slack to popup a dialog with a list of checkboxes containing a list of items that the user must agree to before their post is allowed to be accepted. Only after they check off all items will the post be posted. This is done to ensure that users understand the rules of the channel before posting. Is this possible using Slack's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is something Slack supports. If I understand it right, you want to open a [modal](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals) when a user posts a message on a channel. In order to open a modal, Slack requires a parameter called [`trigger_id`](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#modal_responses). You receive a `trigger_id` when you use any of the [interactive components](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/interactive-components).

Unfortunately, posting a message itself doesn't generate a `trigger_id`. (This would be received by the app as a [message event](https://api.slack.com/events/message), which doesn't contain a `trigger_id`)

An alternate approach could be to respond back with an [ephemeral message](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) or a DM when a user posts a message on a channel. This ephemeral message or the DM could contain an interactive component like a button, which when clicked would open a modal.

Additionally, to [identify a threaded message](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving#finding_threads) as opposed to a message directly posted on a channel, look for `thread_ts` parameter in the message event.